# How does one use SQLite in Perl 6?

Tags: sqlite, raku

I want to start dabbling in Perl 6. A large percentage of my programming involves SQLite databases. It looks like work has been put into using SQLite in Perl 6, but most of the info I can find is old and vague.

I see a "perl6-sqlite" module [here](http://modules.perl6.org/), but it's marked as [old] and has very little to it. I've also seen [references to a new DBI based on something to do with Java](http://blogs.perl.org/users/martin_berends/2010/06/rakudo-perl-6-gets-into-databases.html), but most of that talk is from last year and it's unclear whether there's something that works.

So is there currently an accepted way to use SQLite within Perl 6?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Updated 2015-01): DBIish from https://github.com/perl6/DBIish/ has decent support for SQLite and PostgreSQL, and limited support for mysql.

The README shows how to use it with an SQLite backend.